# Trying to get property of non-object PHP even though it works on my other model

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter to make a query and get the first row that I got. However, PHP gives me a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error. I already tried this same codes on my other model and it worked. I wonder where I went wrong. I'm getting the error on all the `previous_records`.

```
$receivable_query = $this->db->select('invoice_no, cust_name, trans_date, due_date, amount')
                                    ->from('receivable_trans')
                                    ->where('invoice_no', $invoiceNumber)
                                    ->get();

$receivables_row = $receivable_query->row();

$previous_invoice_no = $receivables_row->invoice_no;
$previous_cust_name = $receivables_row->cust_name;
$previous_trans_date = $receivables_row->trans_date;
$previous_due_date = $receivables_row->due_date;
$previous_amount = $receivables_row->amount;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trying to get property of non-object

Probably, you are trying to get a `$receivables_row` property which is non-object value. Inspect what and why `$receivables_row` returns non-object value.

When querying use defensive coding. You can for example have an empty result set, so you should be aware.

```
    if (isset($receivables_row)) {
        $previous_invoice_no = $receivables_row->invoice_no;
        $previous_cust_name = $receivables_row->cust_name;
        $previous_trans_date = $receivables_row->trans_date;
        $previous_due_date = $receivables_row->due_date;
        $previous_amount = $receivables_row->amount;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to inspect the values returned by the query when it is called thru ajax?

Comment: Wrong way. As it is a server side problem debug on server side. You can use for example code-ignitere profiler (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html) to inspect a database queries.  Remember you can type url directly in a browser and see script output if you consider outputting debug info.

Comment: I realized my mistake. I was passing an `$invoiceNumber` that is not existing as a primary key in my database. Therefore, the query returns null resulting to a non-object.